# Variable jump height in Unity jumping to random heights

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to implement a variable jump height system in my game. I stop the jump early by multiplying the velocity by .5f whenever the player releases the jump button (space).

This sometimes works, however sometimes it launches me up randomly when I lightly press space and let go as quickly as I can. It even jumps higher than the maximum jump height I get when I hold space.

This has happened in a project of mine so I thought the project had something wrong with it, I ended up making a new empty project just to test this out. I have no idea whats wrong. I can also confirm it's not an issue with `onGround` because I tried multiple ground sensing methods, and I substituted `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` with `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)` and nothing changed.

Here's the code :

```cs
Rigidbody2D rb;
[SerializeField] float force;
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

bool jump;
[SerializeField] bool onGround;
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && onGround)
    {
        jump = true;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate() 
{
    if(jump)
    {
        //onGround = false;

        jump = false;
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) && rb.velocity.y > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * .5f);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) 
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        onGround = true;
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other) 
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        onGround = false;   
}
```

I have no other scripts attached. Thanks

Comment: "when I lightly press space and let go as quickly as I can", the problem could be that the game doesn't register the `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)`, in which case your code would never stop to send you flying because it would never call `new Vector2(rb.velocity.x,rb.velocity.y*.5f)` (your stopping method : "I stop the jump early by multiplying the velocity by .5f"). And for the problem of jumping higher, maybe the `onGround` variable takes some time to be actualized, in which case you force `jump = true` for longer than what you want

Comment: first of all you should check for `GetKeyUp` also in `Update` just like the `GetKeyDown` .. otherwise you might be simply missing it